# Como manejar los exception en c# con sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, excepciones

Soy algo nuevo en C#, pero tengo la duda de como manejarlos si marca algún error, mandarlo o por ejemplo que tarde mucho la conexión... he buscado con Microsoft y me tope con esto

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                            "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                            "Error Number: " + ex.Errors[i].Number + "\n" +
                            "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                            "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                            "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
}
```

pero no logro entender muy bien ...

Comment: _Por ejemplo que tarde mucho la conexión_ para esto se establece un [`TimeOut`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8) a tu cadena de conexión, y si se sobre pasa el tiempo podrás obtener el mensaje sobre esto asi: `ex.Message`, Aclara un poco mas tu pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente de cual sea la excepción, puedes hacer dos cosas. O tratarla o escalarla.
Ese código, de donde lo hayas sacado (Microsoft es muy grande y puede que en su contexto tuviera sentido pero, tal cual lo muestras no demasiado), lo único que hace, es guardar o mejor dicho, añadir a una colección o a un stringBuilder (desconozco el tipo de errorMensajes), un nuevo objeto tipo string que contiene toda la información que devuelve una excepción sql, para luego darle salida por la consola.
Te digo que no tiene mucho sentido, porque no te va a devolver un array de excepciones, ya que solo tienes un ExecuteNonQuery.

Para el tratamiento de excepciones, existen muchas políticas, o muchas maneras de hacerlo. Todas son buenas y malas. Una opción bastante usada, es utilizar un log, para tratar el mensaje específico de la excepción, y luego escalarla a la parte de la interfaz que ha realizado la petición, con un mensaje al usuario.

Puedes buscar información, ya que es bastante fácil de implementar, por ejemplo, la solución log4net (si pones esto en el buscador de turno, te salen muchas páginas).

Luego de loguear la información técnica, ya puedes tratar la excepción, bien sea realizando algo, o bien sea simplemente haciendo un throw, o generando alguna excepción genérica de algún tipo.

```
  catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                                    "Message: " + ex.Message + "\n" +
                                    "Error Number: " + ex.Number + "\n" +
                                    "LineNumber: " + ex..LineNumber + "\n" +
                                    "Source: " + ex.Source + "\n" +
                                    "Procedure: " + ex.Procedure + "\n");

            Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
            throw new Exception("Ha ocurrido una excepción al intentar realizar xxx");
        }
```

En este link encontrarás un pequeño tutorial sobre el manejo de excepciones que te puede ayudar.

[Excepciones en c#](https://thatcsharpguy.com/posts/excepciones-en-c/)